# Call a CCMenuItem's block programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have the following CCMenuItem:

```
    menuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"example.png" selectedImage:@"example2.png" disabledImage:@"example3.png" block:^(id sender) {
        // do some important things.
    }];
```

where menuItem is a global instance variable.

Is there a way to call the menuItem's block code programmatically? Or do I have to wrap another function in there and then call that? e.g.

```
    menuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"example.png" selectedImage:@"example2.png" disabledImage:@"example3.png" block:^(id sender) {
        [self doThings];
    }];

    ...
    - (void) doThings {
      // do some important things.
    }
```

I'd prefer to just call the block code programmatically.

Comment: You can store the block in an ivar, then you can call it any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call:

> [menuItem activate];

which will invoke the block or the callback. The only caveat with this approach is that to use the vanilla framework method, the menu item must not be disabled. ( must have menuItem.isEnabled = YES )

I prefer to use your second method, though and use a wrapped method and call that externally, exactly because of caveats like I mentioned.